# Angularjs ng-repeat not working in home slider

Tags: html, angularjs, slider, angularjs-ng-repeat, transform

I have a website which uses front end as angularjs. It has a slider in the home page which fetches data from the database to display it. The fetched data cannot be displayed in the slider using ng-repeat.
                 The slider has both images and text which use  data-transform_in and data-transform_out for slider to work.When i am open this page in a browser it shows loading image a while and after that views the last array which fetch from the database and stop working.

Here is my slider section

```
<section id="slider" class="no-padding">
    <div id="slide_1_wrapper" class="rev_slider_wrapper fullwidthbanner-
 container">
      <!-- START REVOLUTION SLIDER 5.0.7 auto mode -->
      <div id="slider_2" class="rev_slider fullwidthabanner slider-home2" 
     style="display:none;" data-version="5.0.7">
        <ul>
          <!-- SLIDE  -->
          <li data-title="FOCUS ON" ng-repeat="sli in sliders">
            <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
            <img src="path/{{sli.background_image}}"  alt="" data-
     bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" 
     class="rev-slidebg" data-no-retina>
            <!-- LAYERS -->
            <!-- LAYER NR. 0 -->
            <div class="tp-caption tp-resizeme sl-s4" 
               data-x="['center','left','left','left']" data-hoffset="
     ['290','0','0','0']"
               data-y="top" data-voffset="160"
               data-width="['580','580','480','320']"
              data-transform_idle="o:1;"
              data-transform_in="x:100px;opacity:0;s:800;e:Power3.easeOut;" 
              data-
       transform_out="s:1000;e:Power3.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power3.easeInOut;" 
              data-start="1500" 
              data-whitespace="['nowrap','nowrap','nowrap','normal']"
              data-fontsize="['32','28','21','16']"
              data-responsive_offset="on" 
              ><p >{{sli.heading}}</p>
            </div>
              .
              .
              .

            <!-- LAYER NR. 4 -->
            <div class="tp-caption" 
               data-x="['center','left','left','left']" data-hoffset="
           ['65','0','0','0']"
               data-y="bottom" data-voffset="['160','160','200','240']"
              data-transform_idle="o:1;"
              data-transform_in="x:100px;opacity:0;s:800;e:Power3.easeOut;" 
              data-
        transform_out="s:1000;e:Power3.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power3.easeInOut;"
              data-start="2100" 
              ><a href="#" class="sl-btn-1">Venue:{{sli.venue}}</a>
            </div>
          </li>
            <!-- /Slider -->
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
     </section>
```

Comment: Have you wrapped your section with controller?

Comment: Yes this section is called from my index.html page